# Strict or Loose equality when comparing to a Symbol?

Tags: javascript

Is strict equality (`===`) ever required when comparing any entity to a Symbol? None of the type conversion rules on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality#description) indicate any conversion to/from a Symbol and a reading of them indicates that it should always be OK (apart from perhaps spoiling code uniformity?) to use `==` when one of the entities is a Symbol.

So can something like

```
function foo(x) {
   return x == somePredefinedSymbol;
}
```

ever go wrong, because as far as I understand the above equality can only return true if `x` *is* `somePredefinedSymbol`?

P.S.: This is just for technical curiosity. I don't intend to advocate the usage of `==`.

Comment: Frame challenge: would you ever want to *not* use strict equality? Except maybe for `x == null`

Comment: @VLAZ I have noticed that sometimes it's useful to check if a value coming from an input (which is always a string) is equal to a certain number without having to check if its a string or a number. Otherwise, it usually doesn't come up.

Comment: @somethinghere `myInput.valueAsNumber` or `Number(value)` is enough for those. I've found that the less mix of comparisons is used, the easier it is to read the code, since you don't have to constantly question "but is this *correct* here, or a bug". It's simple `===` is correct, while `==` might or might not be. The only exception I'd make is for `== null` but I'm also flexible on that.

Comment: @VLAZ Never knew `.valueAsNumber` was a thing. Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So can something like
>
> ```
> function foo(x) {
>    return x == somePredefinedSymbol;
> }
> ```
>
> ever go wrong,

Yes, this is a somewhat constructed example but it does showcase a failure scenario:

```js
const predefinedSymbol = Symbol("foo");

const someObject = {
  value: "bar", // some unrelated values
  [Symbol.toPrimitive]() { // override primitive conversion
    return predefinedSymbol;
  }
}

console.log(someObject ==  predefinedSymbol); //true
console.log(someObject === predefinedSymbol); //false
```

As of ES6 the loose equality will take account of Symbols when compared to an object. From [ECMAScript 6 specification, 7.2.12 Abstract Equality Comparison](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison):

> 10. If Type(x) is either String, Number, or Symbol and Type(y) is Object, then
>     return the result of the comparison x == ToPrimitive(y).
> 11. If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String, Number, or Symbol, then 
>     return the result of the comparison ToPrimitive(x) == y.

Therefore, if an object converted to a primitive produces a symbol *and* that is the same symbol you compare with, then loose equality will produce `true` but using strict equality the result be `false`.